# Python JSON Saving Data to Variable

Tags: python, json

I am running this line of code,

```
m =requests.post(api_url + 'accounts', json=order, auth=auth)
print m.json()
```

which produces the following output:

```
[{u'available': u'0.4', u'balance': u'0.5'}, {u'available': u'6.8', u'balance': u'9.0'}]
```

My goal is to be able to save the different "availables" and "balances" into FLOAT variables, so I can use them further in the code.

Currently, I am trying to do

```
output = float(m['available'])
print(output)
```

But this is not working ... and I am also unsure how to separate them both, given that there is a { curly bracket}  between the two "availables" and "balances"

Comment: Try `m.json['available']`

Comment: ...and when posting questions, "this is not working..." is way too vague. Tell us how its not working, preferably with a stack trace when available. You are making us guess when you have the information.

Comment: Did that work? Let us know so that others don't waste their time pondering the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the json string you get looks like that

```
[
    {
        "available": "0.4",
        "balance": "0.5"
    },
    {
        "available": "6.8",
        "balance": "9.0"
    }
]
```

Which means `m.json()` will return a list with two dictionaries in it .

You should use `float(json[0]['available'])` to get the value .

Comment: Dude, you are really kind !

Comment: I am glad to help :)

Comment: Enjoy the association bonus :grrrrr :D

Comment: thanks, but it seems to not be working... i am getting the error                           `TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__' `.                                The code I am using is                                                                                           `r = requests.get(api_url + 'accounts', auth=auth)`
`print r.json()`

`m = float(json[0]['available'])`
`print m `                  @KIDJourney

Comment: @itsneo help if you can

Comment: @mmk88 Did your check the raw string you get from ```requests.get ``` ? it seems you don't get anything in response .

Comment: @KIDJourney hey , no, when I `print r.json()` i do the get the output as I mentioned (its different from your proposed list ... i have ' instead of ", and I also have the letter u in front of 'available'---- `[{u 'available': u '04'}]` . However, when I do `print m` I get the error

Comment: @mmk88 can you paste your code and i will see what i can do .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105917/discussion-between-mmk88-and-kidjourney).

Comment: i sent the code in the chat - think you can click it to go there @KIDJourney